# Django: how to re-create my function-based view as a (Generic Editing) Class Based View

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, modelform

I have a function-based view that is currently working successfully. However, I want to learn how to create the equivalent Class Based View version of this function, using the generic UpdateView class -- though I imagine the solution, whatever it is, will be the exact same for CreateView, as well.

I know how to create and use Class Based Views generally, but there is one line of my function-based view that I have not been able to work into the corresponding UpdateView -- as usual with the Generic Editing Class Based Views, it's not immediately clear which method I need to override to insert the desired functionality.

The specific task that I can't port-over to the CBV, so to speak, is a line that overrides the queryset that will be used for the display of a specific field, one that is defined as ForeignKey to another model in my database.

First, the working function-based view, with highlight at the specific bit of code I can't get working in the CVB version:

```
@login_required
def update_details(request, pk):
    """update details of an existing record"""
    umd_object = UserMovieDetail.objects.select_related('movie').get(pk=pk)

    movie = umd_object.movie

    if umd_object.user != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserMovieDetailForm(instance=umd_object)

        # this is the single line of code I can't get working in UpdateView version:

        form.fields['user_guess'].queryset = User.objects.filter(related_game_rounds=movie.game_round)

    else:
        form = UserMovieDetailForm(instance=umd_object, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect(movie)

    context = {'form': form, 'object': umd_object }
    return render(request, 'movies/update_details.html', context)
```

I can recreate every part of this function-based view in UpdateView successfully **except** for this line (copied from above for clarity):

```
    form.fields['user_guess'].queryset = User.objects.filter(related_game_rounds=movie.game_round)
```

What this line does: the default Form-field for a ForeignKey  is **ModelChoiceField**, and it by default displays **all** objects of the related Model. My code above overrides that behavior, and says: I only want the form to display this filtered set of objects. It works fine, as is, so long as I'm using this function-based view.

*Side-Note:* I am aware that this result can be achieved by modifying the ModelForm itself in my forms.py file. The purpose of this question is to better understand how to work with the built-in Generic Class Based Views, enabling them to recreate the functionality I can already achieve with function-based views. So please, refrain from answering my question with "why don't you just do this in the form itself instead" -- I am already aware of this option, and it's not what I'm attempting to solve, specifically.

Now for the **UpdateView** (and again, I think it would be the same for **CreateView**). To start off, it would look essentially like this:

```
class UpdateDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserMovieDetail
    template_name = 'movies/update_details.html'
    form_class = UserMovieDetailForm

    login_url = 'login' # used by LoginRequiredMixin

    # what method do I override here, to include that specific line of code, which needs
    # to occur in the GET portion of the view?    

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('movies:movie', kwargs={'pk': self.object.movie.pk, 'slug': self.object.movie.slug })
```

The above is a working re-creation of my function-based view, replicating all the behavior **except** that one important line that filters the results of a specific field's ModelChoiceField display in the Form.

How do I get that line of code to function inside this UpdateView? I've reviewed the methods built-in to UpdateView on the *classy class-based views* website, and then attempted (by pure guess-work) to over-ride the **get_form_class** method, but I it didn't work, and I was basically shooting in the dark to begin with.

Note that since the functionality I want to re-create is about the display of items in ModelChoiceField of the form, the desired behavior applies to the GET portion of the view, rather than the POST. So I need to be able to override the form fields before the form is rendered for the first time, just like I did in my function based view. Where and how can I do this in UpdateView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note not related to form - from `raise Http404` in functional view I understand that you want to allow user to access only his own movies. For that in class based view you can override [get_queryset](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_queryset) method:

```
class UpdateDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserMovieDetail.objects \
            .filter(user=request.user) \
            .select_related('movie')
```

Now let's move to customizing form.

**Option 1 - .get_form()**

You can override [get_form](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_form) method of the UpdateView:

```
class UpdateDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserMovieDetailForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        # add your customizations here
        round = self.object.movie.game_round
        form.fields['user_guess'].queryset = \
            User.objects.filter(related_game_rounds=round)
        return form
```

**Option 2 - moving customizations to form class and .get_form_kwargs()**

You might prefer to move customization logic from view to form. For that you can override form's `__init__` method. If customization logic requires extra information (for example, queryset depends on current user), then you can also override [get_form_kwargs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_form_kwargs) method to pass extra parameters to the form:

```
# views.py
class UpdateDetailsView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserMovieDetailForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'current_user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs


# forms.py
class UserMovieDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.current_user = kwargs.pop('current_user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # add your customizations here
        self.fields['user_guess'].queryset = ...
```

P.S. In general, great resource for understanding django class based views is https://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: @m.arthur - I updated the answer, please take a look

Comment: thank you, excellent stuff. Overriding get_form in the CBV was specifically what I was missing, but the rest is useful as well. Can I ask you though, why the argument form_class=None in the get_form method? And when overriding this method, is it still necessary to assign the form to the form_class attribute?

Comment: Not sure why form_class argument is needed, as I see in django code get_form is always called without parameter. RE form class - you need to pass it if you call super().get_form(). If you don't call super() but rather instantiate the form explicitly, then form_class is not needed.